# From subdomain to root: best approach?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, root

I am not asking for a technical solution, just a plain "what approach would you recommend" vis-a-vis SEO, crawlability and user experience.

Imagine I am selling pastry on my website (let's call it *pastry.com*).
I would like people specifically searching for **cakes** on google to go to my subdomain "*cake.pastry.com*" (listed as such on Google).

But, since I don't want to maintain multiple subdomains, "*cake.pastry.com*" would actually redirect to "*pastry.com#cake*", so that this approach could also be used for cupcakes and muffins! "*cupcake.pastry.com*" redirects to "*pastry.com#cupcake*", etc.

What would be the best way to do this? Is it possible to keep "*cake.pastry.com*" in the address bar while users are actually redirected "*pastry.com#cake*"? Would this pose a UX problem?
Also, will this subdomain bring any value? I.e., will people searching for **cakes** on google actually find the "*cake.pastry.com*" subdomain higher than the root domain (because of keyword density, specificity of content...)? Would I need a 301 or 302 redirect? Via PHP or .htaccess?

So please, any opinion is welcome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot fully answer the SEO parts of this question. But as far as I know, it is no good idea to list a page with different domains at Google. Beside this, subdomains are not made for this purpose. At least I like addresses like http://pastry.com/cake much more than your examples.

The technical answer:

1. You need an wildcard DNS record to map all subdomains to pastry.com
2. You can rewrite with mod_rewrite

I've not tested this, but this is more an example to show how this might work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.pastry\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^pastry\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^\.]+)\.pastry\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://pastry.com/#%1 [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: I see your point!
Would "pastry.com/cake" get listed separatedly on search engines? The whole point of this experiment is to get the user precisely what it was looking for: in this case, cake.

Comment: If there is useful content they should get listed separatedly. This is why we are using landing pages.